# Invalid edit rejected but still approved

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I wanted to know how edit reviews works? Because I rejected one edit which was really invalid. There wasn't need of editing question.

[image: Invalid Approval]

Here is the question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861914/deleting-rows-in-sql-developer-without-using-sql-statement

The suggested edit made the question text looks like "code/commands". But there isn't any need ot highlighting it as command/code block.

How do we report such edit invalid, rather than just reviewing it and rejecting it  (which I already did.)

Comment: horrid edit, but 3 people approved it. It's first to 3, approves vs rejects. I rolled back, considered editing but the post needs major clarifications to avoid closure.

Comment: Down-voters plz post comment as well. I just wanted to know why it happened. Thank you

Comment: @Log1cツ: The grammar stinks and at least one word is missing spacing. People need to take the time to write quality questions.

Comment: @Log1cツ, likely because they thought this could be answered by the help centre. See: [Help Center, Editing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) - "Two (three on Stack Overflow) accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's since been rolled back by OGhaza. I've left a comment for the editor. The edit suggester has left a reply indicating he realises it wasn't right.

This edit should never have been allowed through, I can't imagine what value the reviewers thought the editing added. Bring it up here on Meta is a good option, or if you notice persistent worthless edits getting through you can flag one of the edited posts for ♦ moderator attention (use the *Other* option, and include a link or two to other dodgy edits in the comments for the flag).